# Force a subclass to "implement" the value of a field

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I have a Button baseclass in Java and several types of button subclasses that inherit from this class.
The Button baseclass looks like this:

```
public abstract class BaseButton extends AppCompatButton{

    private ButtonStatus buttonStatus = ButtonStatus.OFF;
    private Image onIcon;
    private Image offIcon;

    public void toggleButton(){

        if(this.buttonStatus == ButtonStatus.ON){
            this.buttonStatus = ButtonStatus.OFF;
            setBackgroundResource(offIcon);
        }else if(this.buttonStatus == ButtonStatus.OFF){
            this.buttonStatus = ButtonStatus.ON;
            setBackgroundResource(onIcon);
        }

    }

}
```

I want each Button subclass to be able to call the `toggleButton()` method, but each of them have a different onIcon and offIcon field. Since I am using these fields in the superclass, I need to have them declared there as well, and they are both instantiated to null.

So whenever I call the `toggleButton()` method from a subclass, the `null` values are used from the superclass. However, I would like to implement this method in the superclass (to avoid code duplication), but still use the subclasses fields.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Add `getOnIcon()` and `getOffIcon()` abstract methods

Comment: (might be a better duplictate, feel free..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass both icons as parameter to the superclass:

```
public abstract class BaseButton extends AppCompatButton{

    private ButtonStatus buttonStatus = ButtonStatus.OFF;
    private Image onIcon;
    private Image offIcon;

    public BaseButton (Image onIcon, Image offIcon){
      this.onIcon = onIcon;
      this.offIcon = offIcon;
    }
    public void toggleButton(){
 // ...
```

and in the Subclass

```
public class SubButton extends BaseButton {
  public SubButton () {
      super(IconSet.SUB_BUTTON_ICON_ON,IconSet.SUB_BUTTON_ICON_OFF);
  }
  // more code
```

Comment: Note that the base class doesn't need to be abstract in your answer.

Comment: @RC. I just adopted the code from the question....

Comment: yes, it's just a "side note"

Comment: @RC I made to base class abstract to prevent it from being instantiated